# Is it possible to create dummy bidders to test header bidding?

Tags: prebid.js

I am a developer curious about header bidding. I don't have demand partners. But I want to test the solution I build. Is it possible to create dummy bidders? Is there any open source code that can mimic a bidder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use appnexus's dummy bidder used in their examples on [prebid.org](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/basic-example.html).
It's also available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prebid/bhn3xk2j/458/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=bhn3xk2j)

Here's the complete configuration:

```
 var adUnits = [{
        code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505748561-0',
        sizes: [[300, 250], [300,600]],
        bids: [{
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '10433394'
            }
        }]
    },{
        code: 'div-gpt-ad-1460505661639-0',
        sizes: [[728, 90], [970, 90]],
        bids: [{
            bidder: 'appnexus',
            params: {
               placementId: '10433394'
            }
        }]
    }];
```

Of course you could also take some else's live configuration, but the owners won't be happy to see your dummy bids